# Recurrence Relation Theta bound

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence of type

T(n)T(n) = T(n/2)T(2n) − T(n)T(n/2)

How to find a theta bound for T(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{T(2n)}{T(n)}=1+\frac{T(n)}{T(n/2)}$$ hence $$\frac{T(2^{k+1})}{T(2^k)}=k+\frac{T(2)}{T(1)},$$ that is, $$T(2^k)=(k+c)(k-1+c)\cdots (1+c)T(1).$$ Thus, $$T(2^k)=k^{k+o(1)},$$ and $$\log T(n)=\Theta((\log n)(\log\log n)).$$

Comment: Could you explain these steps a little more. I am having trouble where you took n = 2^k and reached second part's RHS

Comment: One plugs n=2^k in the first identity then iterates from k, k-1, ... to 1 (what else?).

Comment: Thanks I Understood. But how did you reached step 3? Where did T(2^k+1) go? What is c? Is it T(2)/T(1)?

Comment: Yes I got it. Again recursing on k, k-1... so on.